# How to make a white background in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, background

I'm wondering how can I set a background color to white instead of alpha?

I've already tried more things.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "more things"?  At this time, the question is written it may be likely closed due to no effort and seems to be seeking a tutorial.

Answer (score 5):

Two possible ways:

#### Bucket-fill:

- Remove the selection
- Set color to white
- Activate bucket-fill
- Set bucket-fill to "Behind" mode
- Bucket-fill (due to "Behind" opaque pixels will be left untouched)

#### Layer merge:

- A new layer, fill with required color
- Drag to below the target layer in Layers list (or use `Layer>Stack` menus)
- Activate the target layer and `Layer>Merge down`

Comment: User xenoid has provided a newer answer to a similar question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134081/gimp-how-to-edit-a-sngle-layer-transparency-using-a-white-background/134083#134083