# GIMP: how to edit a sngle-layer transparency using a white background?

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to edit an image that is just one layer which is transparent. It's hard to see the content because of the default gray-black checkered background.

How can this be configured to white?

I'm looking for a proper solution; of course I know the obvious workaround of creating a dummy white layer underneath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `Edit>Preferences>Interface>Display>Transparency>Check style`

You can configure it to "White only"

Comment: Thank you! This question was [asked before](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53626/can-i-change-the-default-gimp-transparent-background-to-white) and the accepted answer was to create a white layer. It was [asked again](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93881/how-to-make-a-white-background-in-gimp) and closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: A small note: in Gimp 2.8.22 on Ubuntu 18.04, the "Display" preference panel is a top-level element of "Preferences", not a child of "Interface".